# Mathjax not rendering fractional exponents

Tags: html, mathjax, fractions

I'm trying to write a blog post including some mathematics with fractional exponents:

```
$x^{3/2}$
```

for example.  However, Mathjax won't render such an exponent: HTML seems to "get to" the fraction `3/2` before Mathjax does, renders it as an HTML fraction, after which Mathjax can do nothing with it.  I can get round this by including a space:

```
$x^{3/ 2}$
```

which fools HTML.  But this seems a bit of a clunky move.  What is the best way of telling my system that Mathjax has priority, so to speak, over HTML?

Comment: HTML is not doing anything to the fraction, but either your content management system (CMS), or possibly a browser plugin, probably is.  One of them is looking through the page before MathJax runs and is converting 3/2 into some more complicated HTML construction.  Try turing off plugins in your browser (if you have any).  If not, then check with the documentation for your CMS and see if it is making the change (you could try viewing the document source and see whether the 3/2 has been changed on the server).  There may be a way to prevent your CMS from altering fractions.

Comment: Many thanks indeed - I'll check all these out.